# how can I reinstall the codecs so I can play my videos back

Tags: video, display, vlc, codecs

I used to play videos from MP4, wma files, as well as form DVDs, but for some reason, I can no more. The file gets loaded and the player starts, but it is always a black screen. No display at all.

What could go wrong ?

Comment: Note: I also get no error message. The player simply starts, but black screen.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **Gnome Terminal** to give you a command-line
2. Manully run `vlc yourmovie.mpg` from the terminal.
3. What debugging/error messages appear?

On the specific point of which packages the codecs live in.  The codecs for certain file-formats can be installed from installing the packages `ubuntu-restricted-addons` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.  You may manually install these packages from the **Ubuntu Software Centre** if you know that you are legally allowed to do so within the juristriction that you live.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the ATI proprietary driver was involved. Something that I still don't understand was making *ANY* video running in BLACK, without an error message. I disabled the proprietary video driver, and the video was working fine. I re-enabled the proprietary driver, and it was still working.